#  Chaos when incorrectly writing to writer during Render() method

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, render

Could someone please explain what is going on here.

I have the following markup:

```
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>My title</title>
    <my:MyControl runat="server" ID="myControl" />
</head>
...
```

My custom control is something like this:

```
public MyControl : Control
{
    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        writer.Write("<script>this is my script</script>");
        base.Render(writer);
    }
}
```

When the page is rendered, the entire top half of the head is chopped off, so the html renders like this:

```
<html>
    <script>this is my script</script>
</head>
```

The solution is to call writer.Write after base.Render, like this:

```
base.Render(writer);
writer.Write("<script>this is my script</script>");
```

Why?!

**UPDATE**

I'm surprised at the amount of interest in this question!

I found out why the top portion of my head tag was being removed - it was a bug with an HttpHandler that I use to 'clean' html (it moves scripts to the bottom etc).

This still doesn't explain exactly why changing the order of the render method would cause the bug to disappear, but I'm sure there is a logical explanation for it all!

Comment: Not much? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.render.aspx

Comment: Interesting. They normally mention such stuff...

Comment: This works for me correctly. (And I don’t see a reason why it shouldn’t.)

Comment: @Mormegil Interesting... must be something else in my codebase that is disturbing it then.

Answer (score 1):

You simply are overwriting your body content with what are you returning from your function:

```
<script>this is my script</script>
```

Comment: There is no "overwriting" going on.

Answer (score 0):

I would look carefully at the rendered HTML in both case. It sounds like your script may be incorrectly rendering, which would cause the following html to fail to render. Changing the order will change the order of your html rendering, which means that the error is not impacting so much of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to correctly override the `Control.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)` method, scroll down to the Examples section:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmltextwriter.aspx

The essential part is

```
        // Create a non-standard markup element.
        writer.RenderBeginTag("MyTag");
        writer.Write("Contents of MyTag");
        writer.RenderEndTag();
        writer.WriteLine();
```

Otherwise you may confuse the `HtmlTextWriter`'s indentation hierarchy etc.

A simpler solution to your concrete example - if you don't want to programmatically change the `<head>` tag's attributes - would be to change the tag `<head runat="server">` to only `<head>`.